# AWS Lambda + Serverless, where/how to deploy js module that couldn't be bundled?

Tags: aws-lambda, angularfire2, serverless, angular-universal, aws-serverless

I have an Angular 8 + Universal (SSR) + Serverless app. Unfortunately it's still using some firebase functionality. I can't bundle firebase when building my project, I have tu exclude it in webpack config here:

```
  externals: [
    /^firebase/
  ],
```

Now how do I provide/add this dependency so that my function works?

In its current state, the app:

- works using `ng serve`
- works as statically hosted
- works served
  as SSR with the local server
- works through `serverless-offline`
  plugin

It's only when actually deployed to lambda that I get the error:

```
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
        "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:36:30)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
        "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
        "    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)",
        "    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)"
    ]
}
```

How could I go about adding this dependency in aws lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you can't bundle the `Firebase` module, but you can deploy a [Lambda layer](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/layers/) with all the required Firebase dependencies and add it to your function.

You can see an example repo [here](https://github.com/erezrokah/lighthouse-layer)

Comment: it's a bug with angular universal/SSR, it throws out an error and on the main github thread about it people were saying to just have it as an 'external' -- I have since added lines about it similarly to aws-express in my yml, including it, as such: '!node_modules/firebase/**' and that has worked but after that it asked for tslib, @firebase/app and I kept adding dependencies there like that, is this normal behaviour?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your exact configuration. Maybe you can share your code here or using a GitHub repo?

Comment: sadly the repo has to be private on this project -- I've made some progress in identifying my issue though: By default, an angular universal app will have all the dependencies it needs to run bundled, but due to firebase not working part of a 'bundle' it needs to be added as an external dependency. All the erros im getting are for dependencies of "firebase" npm module and then their dependencies. Now I'm looking on how to bundle these dependencies or running npm install somehow on the function for that module

Comment: ended up making a layer out of this as well